# Homebrew installed libraries, how do I use them?

Tags: homebrew, unix, open-source, development

I'm a bit confused.

I've installed a bunch of libraries (e.g. `vtk`, `gsl`,...) that I need for a  c++ project for school. I used homebrew to install them (luckily there were formulas available).

My question is, does Homebrew link these into `/usr/include` or something comparable? Or is this something I would need to do manually?

Homebrew usually does this kind of stuff for executables, yet I can't seem the find the libraries anywhere other than in the `/usr/local/Cellar/...` directories. I have a bunch of libraries installed so I can't simply use -L/... for each of them.

Comment: Shouldn't whatever is in the `Cellar` be linked to the `/usr/local`? If it is a project, then I'd suggest using a Makefile; it would make things easier, does it not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are usually linked in `/usr/local/lib` (Intel Macs) or `/opt/homebrew/lib/` (M1 Macs). If they are not there, try `brew link <library-you-are-installing>`; that should solve it.

Answer (score 18):

For recent versions of Homebrew, installed libraries (for example, SDL) will be located in `$(brew --prefix)/lib` as symlinks. Their corresponding header files will be in `$(brew --prefix)/include`.
Generally, when building C or C++ projects you can set the following:

```bash
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include"
```

Usually though, these directories will be automatically discovered and used.

Some Rust projects might require you to set the `LIBRARY_PATH` variable like so:

```bash
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:$(brew --prefix)/lib"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What uses LIBRARY_PATH? It is not the normal thing used in makefiles

Comment: Rust tends to use it for crates that wrap C/C++ libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Use `brew info <package>` to find where a package is installed. You can add the `--verbose` option to see the full list of installed files.

Comment: `--verbose` doesn't show the list of installed files. For that, use `brew ls <package>`